# Custom list View with edit text and check boxes

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I'm new to programming and having problem with using `getCheckedItemPositions()` for check boxes  and getting edit values from edit text in custom list view. Can anyone help me with an example  to create custom list view which has above functionality. Thanks.

*this is custom listview xml code

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:text="CheckBox"
 android:onClick="clickHandler"
 ></CheckBox>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="TextView" 
 android:id="@+id/textView1" 
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
```

android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox">

*This is code for set up listview

lv1 = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.l1);
                adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                            this, 
                            R.layout.custom,
                            cursor2, 
                            new String[] {"ItemName"}, 
                            new int[] {R.id.textView1});

```
         lv1.setItemsCanFocus(false);
         lv1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
         lv1.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

*this what I tried to do  when checked

public void onClick(View v) {

```
                int len = lv1.getCount();
                 SparseBooleanArray checked = lv1.getCheckedItemPositions();
                 for (int i = 0 ; i < len; i++)
                  if (checked.get(i)) {
                   String item = mArrayList.get(i);

                mItems.add(mArrayList.get(i));

             System.out.println(item);




                   /* do whatever you want with the checked item */
                  }
```

But this is not working. And also I want to use edit text in this manner for getting values.when I checked and click the button app terminate.
[image: Logcat when Onclick() trigurred]

Comment: Show us what you have tried so we can tell you where you went wrong... we're not going to do your coding for you.

Comment: @Barak the code i tried is above ..thanks

Comment: @AlexLockwood the code i tried is above ..thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks for the code, now please define "not working".  What is (or is not) happening that you expect (or don't expect)?

Comment: Please post your logcat too, that'll tell us where to look.

Comment: @Barak when I checked Items from my list and triggered onclick() method doesn't give a System.out.println output in logcat. Force close happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will solve your problem.

```
public class SimpleCursorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context mcontext;   
    private View rowview;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public static ArrayList<Boolean > itemchecked=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    public SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> mylist)
    {
        super(context,your layout id);
        mcontext=context;

        //this is the important step    
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) 
        {
            itemchecked.add(i,false); // initializes all items value with false
        }
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        rowview=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            rowview = inflater.inflate(R.yourlayout, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textView_heading = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        CheckBox checkbox_detail=(CheckBox) rowview.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkbox_detail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    itemchecked.set(position, true);
                    // do some operations here
                } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                    itemchecked.set(position, false);
                    // do some operations here
                }   
            }
        });
        checkbox_detail.setChecked(itemchecked.get(position));
        textView_heading.setText(userheading_list.get(position));

        return rowview;
    }   
}
//now the custom list part finish
```

Now, to get all the information from list and also watch which checkbox is checked:

```
for(int i=0;i<yourlistadapterobject.getCount();i++)
{  
    View content_view=msg_adapter.getView(i,null , user_detail_list);
    System.out.println("the list count"+user_detail_list.getCount());
    if(MyContactAdapter.itemchecked.get(i))
    {
        System.out.println("is checked true"); 
        TextView tv_heading=  (TextView) content_view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        String text=tv_heading.getText();
    }
}
```

By doing this, you can get all the information against checkbox which is checked.